# Execute Update Failing with RELATION Error

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

This is what the original code looks like:

```
    boolean passed = false;
    Statement statement = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try 
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUser, DBPassword);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("update tableName set value_start_time = TO_TIMESTAMP('01/" + MonthNumber + "/" + Year + " 11:12:13', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')");
        statement.close();
        conn.commit();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
```

The above code works..

I refactored the code to this:

**Function #1:**

```
public boolean setupDatabaseConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, TestException
    {
        try
        {   
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Handle Exception
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

**Function #2:**

```
public boolean UpdateTableInPostgresDB(String MonthNumber, String Year) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, TestException
    {
        setupDatabaseConnection();
        
        try 
        {
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            PreparedStatements("Update This Table");
            dbPreparedStatement.setString(1, "01/" + MonthNumber + "/" + Year + " 11:12:13");
            dbPreparedStatement.setString(2, "DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS");
            dbPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            dbConnection.commit();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {            
            //Handle Exception            
         }

         return true;
    }
```

**Function #3**

```
public boolean PreparedStatements(String statementToUse) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, TestException
    {
       try
       {
           switch(statementToUse.toLowerCase())
           {
                case "update this table" :
                {
                  dbQuery = "update tableName set value_start_time = TO_TIMESTAMP(?, ?)";
                  break;
                }
           }

           dbPreparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(dbQuery);

       {
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          //Handle Exception
       }
```

Now it's failing in **Function #2** at the line where I need to do this:

```
dbPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The exception being caught is:

> ERROR: relation "tableName" does not exist   Position: 8

I don't know why this isn't working to be honest.. I do plenty other SQL queries with the same prepared statements function.

Comment: `"tableName"` is a different name than `tableName` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do know the difference for PSQL with quoted table names, however, this is not the case with this situation. As mentioned in the post, it's the same statement and the one method works where the other one doesn't.

Comment: Well, then the table has a different name, or doesn't exist or you are not connecting to the database you think you are

Answer (score 1):

hope you are using the table name in the proper case as Postgres is case sensitive for the database object for eg. if you use "tabeName" is different then "tablename"

make sure you include the schema name with the table name if it is applicable then

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As mentioned in the comment on the post, I do know the difference for PSQL with quoted table names, however, this is not the case with this situation. It's the same statement and the one method works where the other one doesn't.